# How to initialize an array of objects when an array of double is already set?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to initialize an array of particles where Particle is a class I defined. I'm told [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/initialize-object-arrays.html) that I should do it like that

`particles(2, 1) = Particle();`

but this doesn't work if `particles` has been previously set to something like an array of doubles, or may be larger than the intended size (and won't shrink with this line, only the affected row will be changed I think). Is there a way to unset the variable to initialize my array fresh?

The error I get:

> The following error occurred converting from Particle to double:
>   Conversion to double from Particle is not possible.
>
> Error in main (line 4) particles(2, 1) = Particle();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various possible solutions. To clear a variable, use `clear`:

```
clear particles
particles(2, 1) = Particle;
```

(Note it's not necessary to add the empty parenthesis to call a function without arguments.)

However, a better solution IMO is to create an array of your class and assign it to the variable

```
particles = repmat(Particle,2,1);
```

This statement only works if you haven't overloaded the concatenation operator.